# How to update web browser on selenium/node-chrome inside docker

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-hub

I had to update my web browser inside docker file, because I get on my tests report that banner, and it's failed my automation tests.[image]

I don't know how to update that. Should I do it through docker update container? Or should I delete selenium/node-chrome add push into docker new container?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution:

1. Go into folder with docker-compose.yml file (if you don't have - you should grab from [enter link description here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)
2. Synchronize with service image registry `docker-compose pull`
3. Recreate container if docker-compose file or image have changed:`docker-compose up -d`

after those steps browser should be updated